# Checking URL Status without Throwing Error

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I'm looking to check to see if 500+ strings in a given dataframe are URLs. I've seen that this can be done using the `requests` package but I've found that if I provide a URL, instead of receiving the error code 404, my program is crashing.

Because I'm looking to apply this function to a dataframe with many strings not being active URLs, the current function would not work for what I'm looking to accomplish.

I'm wondering if there is a way to adapt the coded below to actually return no (or anything else) in the case that the URL isn't real. For example, providing the url 'http://www.example.commmm' results in an error:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://www.example.com')
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: simply use `try/except` to catch error

Answer (score 1):

I would try and add a try/except to prevent your code from breaking

```
try:
  print(x)
except:
  print("An exception occurred")
```